# Passing Bitmap to another Activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, hashmap

I have a HashMap of Bitmap images, declared like this:

```
var cachedImages : HashMap<String, Bitmap?> = HashMap()
```

And I fetch one of them like so:

```
val imageNeeded = cachedImages.get("imgKey")
```

How can I pass this Bitmap? to the next activity so I can use it there?

Comment: Do not pass a Map of Bitmap in activity instead pass an array of Uri(s) because Bitmaps are normally heavy while the Intent can only carry a limited amount of load. In order to obtain a Uri you must store the image within the device storage. This approach is applicable in both Java and Kotlin.

Comment: Another approach is to build a Singleton cache where your cache is temporarily living in the memory, although this approach requires you to know the possible risk of using static variable if not handled correctly.